# Use vector of strings for loop vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to use the following vector as loop vector in matlab:

```
year = ['JAN';'FEB';'MAR';'APR';'MAY';'JUN';'JUL';'AUG';'SEP';'OCT';'NOV';'DEC'];
```

The loop is

```
for i = year
    %Do something
    i
end
```

Unfortunately i is only one sign, and not three, i.e. I am expecting an output from the above as

```
JAN
FEB
MAR
APR
.
.
.
```

but I get only

```
J
F
M
A
M
.
.
.
```

How can I change that? Or should I rather use a look-up-table, and loop over a vector from 1 to 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got is a 12x3 matrix. To iterate over all rows you have to use matrix indexing:

```
for month=1:size(year,1)
   year(month,:)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that that is a 12x1-string-matrix.

Comment: There is no `string` class in matlab, there is only `char`. A very common error. Details here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strings.html